# Database tables viewing and filtering app in Django

Tags: python, django, database-management

Up to this point I was using django's admin app as a base.

It seemed great at first but when I got to the point that I want to present the data from tables and enable user to search and filter columns I noted that the 'admin' app was really not meant to be used in such context.

Is if there is a better base that I could use?

I searched [django packages repository](http://djangopackages.org) but could not find any app devoted to the above problem specifically.

**edit**: I am looking not only for 'ready to use packages', if there are some open source projects that have the functionality I need I can fork the part of the code and possibly share the resulting app.

Answer (score 1):

Django admin app has huge amount of possibilities for searching and filtering. Seriously, take a good look on [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/) on admin interface customisation.

If it is not enough — you can make your own app which will do exactly what you want. But I doubt if you'll find in packages repository something you can just add to your apps section in `settings.py`.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I think I will go with creating an app for the functionality I need. With that said it would be a lot easier if there would be some project which I could use as a base.

Comment: @Raff89 I believe it shouldn't be too hard to implement it from scratch.

Comment: @Raff89 actually, it's nice task to dive in Django with.

Comment: I will do just that. thanks for constructive responses.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the Django admin app is not really meant to be used by end-users who are not developers. One package that might help you is [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter). It's not a drop-in replacement for the Django admin, but it is a great help when you need to do filtering.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I will definitely check that package